# Maximum number of table columns in Clickhouse

Tags: olap, clickhouse

I've tried to test the boundries and noticed that if I have 5K columns in the table, even when I try to insert only 2 columns values, I get a
 Received from 127.0.0.1:9000. DB::Exception: Memory limit (for query) exceeded: would use 9.31 GiB

is there a way to handle extremely large number of metrics?

what's the actual limit for the number of columns in a single table?

Answer (score 2):

I think the limit is none (except your hardware limitations). Try to increase max memory usage for your query

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/settings/query_complexity/#settings_max_memory_usage

Answer (score 0):

ClickHouse allocate around 1-2Mb per column when you try insert any rows, so right answer is yes, it has not strict limit but limited by your CPU, Memory, concurrent client connections with insert and for *MergeTree table engines also restricted by number of partitions (see PARTITION BY in docs)

Comment: Thank you.
what's odd though is that when I have 5000 columns and I use an insert statement of just 2 of them, with only several bytes each, I still get thrown by an exception.

is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: how other 4998 columns in this table were defined?
which datatype was used?
which default value was used?

Comment: 4500 strings and 500 Int32 ,  didn't set any default

Comment: do you mean 4500 string without usage Nullable?
so, when you define ```field String```, it's mean ```field String DEFAULT ''``` and ```field Int32``` means ```field Int32 DEFAULT  0``` 

and I think you just try to allocate 2Mb* 5000 columns, in this case

Comment: I also tried the following 


CREATE TABLE test(
lc0 Nullable(String) default NULL,
lc1 Nullable(String) default NULL,
lc2 Nullable(String) default NULL,
lc3 Nullable(String) default NULL,
....
lc5000 ... 
}

and then ran   'insert into test(lc1,pk) values('12','231') 

and got the same outcome

Comment: `'insert into test(lc1,pk)` it does not matter. CH still use 5000*2MB = 10GB memory for this insert. You can reduce min_compress_block_size / max_compress_block_size. But the issue is the number of columns. CH recommends up to 1000 columns. Try arrays.